# How to make a program in JavaScript where the consonants in a given string are doubled?

Tags: javascript

So, the question I'm working through is this,

> Write a JavaScript function that accepts a string as a parameter and will return a similar string, but with each consonant doubled.
>
> Here is an example:
>
> ```js
> doubleConsonants("Johnathan"); // returns "JJohhnnatthhann"
> doubleConsonants("racecar"); // returns "rracceccarr"
> ```
>
> **!!! We must assume that the strings do not contain any spaces !!!**

So far, this is all the code I have and now, I'm not sure how to proceed. Could someone please help me?

```js
function doubleConsonants(string) {
  let consonants = 
  [
    'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'z'
  ];
}
```

I know it's not too much to go off of but I'd really appreaciate it if someone could help me.

Comment: A `for` loop and `array.push` and `array.includes` come to mind. Also, using an array which contains all `vowels` would be shorter and you can check each character to see if it is a vowel instead of if it is a consonant.

Comment: It's all good everyone. Thank you all for your responses and solutions, they were much appreciated! But apparently, we were not supposed to use arrays when creating the program. I did find a solution though but it isn't mine to share. It was developed by someone else and they don't want me sharing it so, I will not be posting an answer. But, I found all of your answers very helpful, so thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple way with a regular expression:

If the character is not `a`,`e`,`i`,`o`, or `u`, then we repeat the character a second time.

```js
const doubleConsonants = s => s.replace(/[^aeiou]/gi, char => char.repeat(2));

console.log(doubleConsonants("Johnathan"));
console.log(doubleConsonants("racecar"));
```

Regex explanation:

```
/[^aeiou]/gi     
/              Start the regex
 [      ]      anything that matches here
  ^            actually, match anything that's not here
   aeiou       list of all the vowels (so match anything that **isn't** a vowel)
         /     stop the regex
          g    "global", check every single occurance
           i   "ignore case", don't differentiate `a` and `A`
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Iterate the array and use a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).
2. Check if the variable is a consonant with an [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).
3. If it is a consonant, return the letter twice otherwise once

Also, use [`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) so that you don't have to have a separate array of uppercase consonants.

```js
const consonantsArr = [
  // "a",
  "b", "c", "d", // "e",
  "f", "g", "h", // "i",
  "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", // "o",
  "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", // "u",
  "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"
];

/**
 * Double the consonants in a string
 * @param {string} str The input string
 * @returns {string} The input string with doubled consonants
 */
function doubleConsonants(str) {
  return Array
    .from(str) // Make an array out of the input to use Array methods
    .reduce((acc, b) => { // Reduce the array for string concat
      return acc + (
        consonantsArr.includes(b.toLowerCase()) ? // Check if b is a consonant
        b + b : // Double it if it is
        b // Otherwise pass it through
      );
    }, ""); // Start reduce with empty string
}

console.log(doubleConsonants("Johnathan")); // JJohhnnatthhann
console.log(doubleConsonants("racecar")); // rracceccarr
console.log(doubleConsonants("abc123")); // abbcc123
```

---

You can also *not* double vowels as [Alex Mckay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64899559/691711) suggests, but you could end up with doubled characters that aren't consonants if they are allowed (like `abc123 -> abbcc112233`).

```js
const vowelsArr = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];

/**
 * Double everything but vowels in a string
 * @param {string} str The input string
 * @returns {string} The input string with the transform
 */
function dontDoubleVowels(str) {
  return Array
    .from(str) // Make an array out of the input to use Array methods
    .reduce((acc, b) => { // Reduce the array for string concat
      return acc + ( // Always concat with accumulator
        !vowelsArr.includes(b.toLowerCase()) ? // Check if b is a vowel
        b + b : // Double it if it is not
        b // Otherwise pass it through
      );
    }, ""); // Start reduce with empty string
}

console.log(dontDoubleVowels("Johnathan")); // JJohhnnatthhann
console.log(dontDoubleVowels("racecar")); // rracceccarr
console.log(dontDoubleVowels("abc123")); // abbcc112233
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simplest way I could think of:

```js
const vowels = 'a,e,i,o,u'.split()

str.reduce((nextStr, letter) => {
  if (vowels.includes(letter)) return nextStr + letter
  else return nextStr + letter + letter
}, '')
```

Sorry about the dodgy formatting I am on my phone!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can think of is to use a [RegEx](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)-based [string replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a replacement function. The code example I've included below basically takes your array of consonants and turns them into a pattern: `/[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz]/gi`.

```js
function doubleConsonants(str) {
  const consonants = [ 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'z' ];

  const re = new RegExp(`[${consonants.join('')}]`, 'gi');
  return str.replace(re, match => match + match);
}

console.log(doubleConsonants('Johnathan') === 'JJohhnnatthhann');
console.log(doubleConsonants('racecar') === 'rracceccarr');
```

If the array isn't required, you could further simplify the code by just using that exact pattern. (Arrow function used for even more brevity):

```js
const doubleConsonants = str =>
  str.replace(/[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz]/gi, match => match + match)

console.log(doubleConsonants('Johnathan') === 'JJohhnnatthhann');
console.log(doubleConsonants('racecar') === 'rracceccarr');
```